# AnguarJS: Bind dynamically created controls to model

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, dynamically-generated

I need to create a GUI on the fly depending on the input of the user. One use case is, that the user enters the number of headlines he/she wants to have on a generated report. Therefore I render input controls via ng-repeat which works fine. In those rendered input tags it must be possible to enter the headline for the report.

The only problem is that I have no clue how to bind the input of the textboxes to a model because the number of the input controls are different every time.

The View:

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="Controller">
        <input type="number" ng-model="numberOfCtrls"/>
        <div ng-repeat="i in getTimes(numberOfCtrls) track by $index">
            <input type="text" style="width:100px;" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Controller:

```
function Controller($scope){
 $scope.numberOfCtrls = 0;   
 $scope.tempNumber = 0;

 $scope.getTimes = function(number){

   return new Array(number);   
 };
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/5dzvnbtt/

Thxs in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can populate a variable with the desired amount of headline objects.

Here's an example:

```
$scope.headlines = [];

$scope.$watch('numberOfHeadlines', function() {
    $scope.headlines = [];
    if ($scope.numberOfHeadlines !== undefined) {
        for (i = 0; i < $scope.numberOfHeadlines; i++) {
            $scope.headlines.push({ title: '' });
        };          
    }

});
```

And the template:

```
<select ng-model="numberOfHeadlines">
    <option value="">Choose headlines</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<div ng-repeat="headline in headlines">
    Headline {{ $index + 1 }} is: {{ headline.title }}
    <br />
    <input type="text" ng-model="headline.title">
    <hr />
</div>
```

And a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/10985/) demonstrating it.

Comment: Thanks, this works for me! The only thing I don't get, is why does it only works with an object and not with plain string values; just ng-model="headline" instead of ng-model="headerline.title"